# How can I get items closer in ion-col?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have 2 cols elements but they are too far away, how can I get them closer?
If I put size="5" and size="7" it becomes like this:

[image]

If I put size="4" and size="8" it overlaps even with pre-line the content of the first column goes in another line.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: <ion-item [hidden]="edit == true">
        <ion-row class="whatsapp-row">
          <ion-col size="5">
            <ion-label class="whatsapp-label" position="stacked">Contato 1* </ion-label>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="7">
            <ion-img class="whatsapp"></ion-img>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-input required [(ngModel)]="aluno.contato1" [brmasker]="{mask: '(00) 00000-0000', len:15, type:'num'}" (ionBlur)="validaContato1(aluno.contato1)" (ionChange)="validaContato1(aluno.contato1)" name="contato1"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

Comment: see this https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities
you can use predefined css classes.. ion-float-right should work..

Comment: Remove the padding